# Android: declined permission for vibrator (what happens?)

Tags: android, permissions, vibration

I have made an app that has a permission for use of the vibrator. When I install that app, how do I get to accept or decline that permission? It seems like I have no knowledge of the permission and it just installs without asking me..

Also, say I did decline that permission. Would it stop the whole app from working or would it just stop the vibrator from working? If it just stops the vibrator from working, would it just skip the java code referring to the vibrator and carry on as normal?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user is notified of the required permissions when they choose to install it from Android Market. Users don't get to choose to allow or deny this or that permission; they are notified of the permissions the app requires, and by choosing to install the app they are accepting that the require permissions will be granted.

If a new version of your app were to add new permissions, it would become a manual upgrade, and the user would have to accept the new permissions in order to upgrade to the new version.

But users can't selectively deny permissions to software at the time of installation; that's not how Android permissions work.

Answer (score 1):

When Android apps are installed a nice big warning prompt shows up informing the user of all permissions requested by the application.  At this point the user may accept or decline.  If the user accepts, then the application is installed.  If they decline, the application is not installed.

You cannot accept or decline specific permissions, it's an all-or-nothing situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall your app then reinstall it and see if the permission to virabte is asked to user. You can't selectively grant permission on android. Either app is installed as you agreed for all requested permission or it won't install.

Look in your settings if your phone vibrator is active.

Does your phone have a vibrator ?

Comment: also try to unconnect usb support. I know a phone that prevents leds to turn on when plugged, maybe some do that for vibrator as well.